# Go to current active activity after the OK button of a dialog box is clicked in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have developed an application with both Activity and a background `Service`. My main `Activity A` is a `Tab Host` which starts the `Service S and Activity B,C and D with tabs via Intent`.

The Service `S` gets data from a remote database and stores it in the application's local database.

If there is a data from the `Remote database`, the `Service S starts an Activity E with an Alert Box`. Once i click the `OK button of the Alert Box`, the main Activity A(Tab Host) is opened.

Imagine the user is in Activity B and if the dialog box opens, after clicking OK button the user is switched to Activity A rather than Activity B. How can i go to Activity B(current active activity)?.

Part of Activity with Alert box.

```
public class Popup extends Activity{
int value = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        value = extras.getInt("key") ;     
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    if(value == 1){
        builder.setMessage(value +  "new task has been assigned").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //mp.stop();

                Popup.this.finish();

            }
        }).show();
    }

    else {
        builder.setMessage(value + " " + "new tasks has been assigned").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //mp.stop();

            }
        }).show();
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the code with on your `onClick Event`  in `AlertBox` keep it Blankl to remain on Same Activity

like

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    if(value == 1){
        builder.setMessage(value +  "new task has been assigned").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    }).show();
}

else {
    builder.setMessage(value + " " + "new tasks has been assigned").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A (TabHost), use the TabHost `getCurrentTab` method to determine the current tab, and `setCurrentTab` to set the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

your current activity will be in onPause() state when alert box comes,so need to ovveride onPause() method and set some boolean varible to true and then do your further stuff in onResume() method,like this

```
private boolean state=false;
    onPause(){
    state=true;
super.onPause();
}
onResume(){
  if(state==true){
//do your required stuff,for  example you want to stay in current activity(B)
       A.tabHost.setCurrentTab(here set B activity tab index);//declare tabHost variable as public static in activity A.
 super.onResume();
```

}

}